# Chromium browsers (Chrome/Brave) toggle device toolbar and profile switching have the same keyboard shortcut (how to override)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, brave

Specifically I'm using Brave the but the issue also appears in Chrome (and I assume other chromium browsers). When you press cmd+shift+m you get the profile switcher. However, if you have the dev tools open then cmd+shift+m with toggle device toolbar instead. It's pretty frustrating as I'm always just trying to profile switch.

Is there a way to remove the keyboard shortcut from toggle device toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

Dev Tools can change its keyboard shortcuts. Open Dev Tools and then its menu (the 3 dots) and shortcuts. Then remove (or change) the "Toggle device toolbar" shortcut.